# HTML controls overlapping with Flash Object in IE 11

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer-11, fusioncharts

My application has some JQuery controls which seem to be overlapping with the a flash object (Fusion charts graph). 
I tried setting z-index,setTransparent to true, WMode to transparent. None of them seem to work in IE 11 browser. This doesnt show issue in any other browsers. Any idea how to fix this for fusion charts v3 and IE 11 combination ? 
Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the rendering to JavaScript mode and check if the issue still persist? Using v3.2, try setting current renderer as JavaScript.

Else, try using the latest version.